# Counterexample for ∀x∃y (x=1/y)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, examples-counterexamples

So I am working on this math problem which states that for every x (domain: all integers) there is a y (domain: all integers) for which x=1/y is true.

> ∀x∃y (x=1/y)

If I understand this correctly, it means that there is some y for every x in the set of integers which makes x=1/y always true. This is false, but I don't understand how to show a counterexample for this one. I could try explaining how this is not false but aside from that, I am not sure what to do.

Comment: What is the domain for $y$?

Comment: The statement says that for any integer $x$, there is some $y$ (what kind of $y$?  an integer?  a rational?  and extended real?) such that $x = \frac{1}{y}$.  A counterexample would be an integer $x$ that cannot be written as the reciprocal of some $y$ (wherever $y$ is meant to live).  $x=0$ might be a good candidate.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @XanderHenderson $x=0$ is good for any domain for $y$ :)

Comment: @szw1710 Not necessarily.  For example, in the extended reals or the Riemann sphere, $0 = 1/\infty$, right?  But in those contexts, there may not be a counterexample.  Which is why it is important to know where $y$ lives. :)

Comment: @XanderHenderson This is the only case. What I wrote in my answer, $x=0$ is good for any subset of reals, when we don't consider extended reals. Thanks for a detail you turned my attention to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not good understanding. The formula says that **any** $x\in\Bbb Z$ is the inverse of **some** $y\in\Bbb Z$. This is evidently false. The counterexample is $x=2$. There is no $y\in\Bbb Z$ s.t. $2=\dfrac{1}{y}$ (if should be $y=\dfrac{1}{2}\not\in\Bbb Z$). So, the negation is true: there exists $x\in\Bbb Z$ ($x=2$) s.t. for all $y\in\Bbb Z$ we have $x\ne\dfrac{1}{y}$.

My answer is good, if the domain for $y$ is the set of all integers. Nevertheless, if the domain for $y$ is any subset of raeals, it is enough to take $x=0$ for the counterexample.

Comment: I got it, and I understand that I kind of reversed the reasoning in my initial post which was incorrect. I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @AvenNova It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

To stress how your understanding is wrong, you're doing the qualifiers in the word order. $\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ is almost never logical equivalent to $\exists y \forall x P(x,y)$. This says that for every integer there is some integer that is the inverse, not the reverse as you've said. Both are false, but they're very different sentiments.